# Preventing form submission on Enter key press in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

There are so many answers for this on stackoverflow. But unfortunately none of them is working for me. I will tell you what I have tried one by one.

1. `<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" ...>`
2. `<button (keyup.enter)="skillsHandleEnter($event, skillString)"></button>`

   @Component(...)
   class MyComponent {
     skillsHandleEnter(event, skillString) {
       event.preventDefault();
       // ... your logic
     }
   }

But none of the approach is working. I am using `ngx-tags-input` which allows me to apply some tags separated by `enter` key. This creates a problem. The moment I press Enter key, my form gets submitted with just one tag that i was able to enter. Trust me I've tried almost everything to prevent this and also I dont want to over complicate the things. Please ignore naming conventions. I will fix them later.

Here's my **blog.component.html** before implementing any solution.

```
<form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a question that explains your problem exactly">
    <br>
    <label for="editor">
      <h3>Editor</h3>
    </label>
    <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
  </div>
  <ngx-tags-input class="form-control input-lg" name="tags"></ngx-tags-input>
  <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please correct me.

Comment: `(onSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"`, `function onSubmit(f) { f.preventDefault(); }` or similour.

Comment: Hi @Tanzeel if any of the answera has solve your question please consider accept it.This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 

Comment: @malbarmawi. I understand this. But none of the answers solved my problem. I came up with my own solution that I'm posting now. Hope you'll accept and up vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed these two simple steps:

1) I added an attribute in my `form` tag.

`(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"`

2) Added `(click)` listener on the submit button

So the entire HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 bg-light">
      <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
        <div class="form-group">
                    ...
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem was that I was using click listener with the `form` tag itself along with `keydown.enter`.

Comment: This will prevent normal functions of controls in the form, e.g. textarea won't insert Newline on enter.

Answer (score 1):

the html [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element  has a three valid type

1. **submit** : the button submits the form data to the server. This is the **default**  if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribut is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
2. **reset**: The button resets all the controls to their initial values,
   like . button: The button has no default
   behavior and does nothing when pressed. It can have client-side
   scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered
   when the events occur.
3. **button**: the button has no default behavior and does nothing when
   pressed. It can have client-side scripts associated with the
   element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

so to solve the probleb just set the button type to *button* like this

```html
<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

The only reason to use `ngSubmit` is to submit the form on "enter".
So you can remove the `ngSubmit` event listening and replace it by the `click` event of the button. I also removed the submit emitting from the button by adding `type="button"`.

```
<form [formGroup]="editorForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter a question that explains your problem exactly">
    <br>
    <label for="editor">
      <h3>Editor</h3>
    </label>
    <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
  </div>
  <ngx-tags-input class="form-control input-lg" name="tags"></ngx-tags-input>
  <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3">Submit</button>
</form>
```